# Does anyone know how I could make this code easier to read and take up less lines of space?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I have written this code to create in pattern in certain manner using the turtle module in python. I am trying to simplify it down to less lines of code but I am unsure of how to do so in a manner that will make it work in the exact same fashion.

```
import turtle
t = turtle.Turtle()
t.speed(0)

t.penup()
t.setposition(120, 210)
t.pendown()

t.speed(5)
t.width(2)
length = 80
colors = ["purple", "blue", "green", "orange", "red"]

t.color(colors[0])
for purple_side in range(1, 4):
    t.forward(length)
    if purple_side % 3 != 0:
        t.right(90)

t.color(colors[1])
for blue_side in range(1, 3):
  t.forward(length)
  if blue_side % 2 != 0:
    t.left(90)

t.color(colors[2])
for green_side in range(1, 3):
  t.forward(length)
  if green_side % 2 != 0:
    t.right(90)

t.color(colors[3])
for yellow_side in range(1, 3):
  t.forward(length)
  if yellow_side % 2 != 0:
    t.left(90)

t.color(colors[4])
for red_side in range(1, 5):
  t.forward(length)
  if red_side % 4 != 0:
    t.right(90)

t.color(colors[3])
for yellow_side in range(1, 3):
  t.forward(length)
  if yellow_side % 2 != 0:
    t.left(90)

t.color(colors[2])
for green_side in range(1, 3):
  t.forward(length)
  if green_side % 2 != 0:
    t.right(90)

t.color(colors[1])
for blue_side in range(1, 3):
  t.forward(length)
  if blue_side % 2 != 0:
    t.left(90)
  else:
    t.color(colors[0])
    t.forward(length)
    t.right(90)
```

I have tried many different things to simplify this code with no luck.

Comment: This may be more on topic for [code review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) if it already works. Be sure to [take their tour](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour/) if you're new to the site.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the pattern you have drawn gives a clue, you might find things much simpler if you think at a higher level about what you are trying to do.

First, note that each square is joined at the top right and bottom left, your code will be simpler if you also start in the same place.

Second, note that the reverse trip is the same as the trip down but with the colours in reverse order.

```
import turtle
t = turtle.Turtle()
t.speed(0)

t.penup()
t.setposition(120, 210)
t.pendown()

t.speed(5)
t.width(2)

t.right(90) # the turtle starts facing to the right, but each half square begins facing down

length = 80
colors = ["purple", "blue", "green", "orange", "red"]

def drawHalfSquare(color):
    t.color(color)
    t.forward(length)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(length)
    t.left(90)

for color in colors:
    drawHalfSquare(color)
    
# turn around at the end to face up
t.right(180)

for color in colors[::-1]: #[::-1 will reverse the list]
    drawHalfSquare(color)
```

Answer (score 0):

First study the symmetry of what you're trying to draw.  For example, starting at the first down stroke, rather than right stroke, makes the first square the same as the others and not a special case.

Although it might appear quite different, this solution shares some of the same basic drawing concepts as @Turksarama's nice solution (+1):

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

COLORS = ['purple', 'blue', 'green', 'orange', 'red']
LENGTH = 80

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.speed('fastest')
turtle.width(2)
turtle.right(90)

turtle.penup()
turtle.setposition(len(COLORS) / 2 * LENGTH, len(COLORS) / 2 * LENGTH)
turtle.pendown()

for color in [*COLORS, None, *reversed(COLORS)]:

    if color:
        turtle.color(color)

        turtle.forward(LENGTH)
        turtle.right(90)
        turtle.forward(LENGTH)
    else:
        turtle.left(90)

    turtle.left(90)

turtle.hideturtle()
screen.exitonclick()
```